# java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException of Jenkins when Jenkins container accessing the local folder on my system

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have run the Jenkins Docker Container. When Jenkins is up, I have created a new item by name Ant_Build. Under Ant_Build configurations, for General tab and when clicked on Advanced, I have checked the 'Use Custom Workspace' and have provided the value as D:\BuildSourceCode\CRONUS\RM_OFFICE\RMRest

Under Build configurations, I have provided Build File location as: D:\BuildSourceCode\CRONUS\RM_OFFICE\RMRest\Sources\BuildFiles\build.xml

I have provided Properties location as D:\BuildSourceCode\CRONUS\RM_OFFICE\RMRest\Sources\build.properties

When I clicked on Build Now for Ant_Build, I am getting the following error.

```
Console Output: 
  
    Started by user admin
    Running as SYSTEM
    Building in workspace D:\BuildSourceCode\CRONUS\RM_OFFICE\RMRest
    java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /D:\BuildSourceCode\CRONUS\RM_OFFICE\RMRest
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:384)
        at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:674)
        at java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:781)
        at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:767)
        at hudson.FilePath.mkdirs(FilePath.java:3260)
        at hudson.FilePath.access$1300(FilePath.java:211)
        at hudson.FilePath$Mkdirs.invoke(FilePath.java:1251)
        at hudson.FilePath$Mkdirs.invoke(FilePath.java:1247)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1075)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1058)
        at hudson.FilePath.mkdirs(FilePath.java:1243)
        at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1200)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
        at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1880)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
    Finished: FAILURE
```

Can anyone help me execute the Ant_Build job correctly on Jenkins Docker Container ?

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the below link, it's provided by Jenkins

https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md

I used the below command :

docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -u root jenkins/jenkins